# Python: Creating a 8*8 2D grid on screen

Tags: python

Basically I want an 8*8 2D grid on screen that i can fill with RGB colors. How would I go about defining this? I'm new to Python obviously.

Like if I did this it would fill the 64 pixels with white color

```
colors = (255,255,255)
for i in range(0, 8):
    for j in range(0, 8):
        matrix[i][j] = colors
```

Where matrix would be the 64 pixel space

Comment: Probably `pygame` library. Look for tutorials, consulting you with details would be too long

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. It seems I have substantially underestimated the work involved.

Comment: Windows, graphical interface, computer graphics are never simple, even with Python

Comment: use pygame library for canvas creation, in your way you can only output to standard output console/terminal.